# convert string in Python from ascii to utf-8 and back

Tags: python, utf-8

I have a string variable `blah` that I am trying to send to Python's `print` and I get this error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 26892-26894: ordinal not in range(128)`

The text is coming from a windows server via WMI. So I tried this:

```
try:      
    print(blah, end='')  
except: 
    print(blah.encode('utf-8'), end='')
```

This catches the error, but now my `blah` variable looks like this:

`b'line#1\nline#2\nline#3\nline#4'`

However, I need to send the output of this Python program to a daemon that expects the original format,

```
line#1
line#2
line#3
line#4
```

Which is what I really want. I tried chaining it with `string.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8','errors=ignore')` but apparently my version of Python doesn't accept this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using shell redirection to pipe the output of Python to the daemon?  Set the  environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` before starting Python.  Another option is run Python with the `-X utf8` switch to force its I/O interfaces to use UTF-8.  Python assumes `ascii` when redirected otherwise.

Comment: I tried with `os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING'] = 'utf8'` at the top of the file but no difference.

Comment: Set it in the shell before starting Python.  It's too late doing it *in* Python.

Comment: I also tried this in Windows: add `#!python3 -X utf8` as the first line of the script.  It worked.  Linux you may have to add the path such as `#!/usr/bin/python3 -X utf8`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't guarantee the environment this code runs in.

Comment: I tried the `#!/usr/bin/python3 -X utf8` and it doesn't make a difference. I'm on 3.4 though.

Comment: [[Python 3.4 doesn't have the `-X utf8` switch](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html#using-on-cmdline).  Use [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonioencoding#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable.